# Motion in space

Tags: special-relativity, forces, speed-of-light, drag, rocket-science

1. Does a space shuttle travelling in space experience any resistance to its motion?
2. If a body in space is applied constant force, does it attain speed of light after sufficient time?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes a spacecraft traveling through space experiences some opposing force or drag through particles and radiation. Most of what we consider vacuum is filled with gas, photons and a sea of subatomic particles that will interact with the craft and change its momentum. 
   Even in a complete vacuum it is possible that quantum mechanical field fluctuations, especially of the electromagnetic field, affect the craft's motion.
2. A constant force will *never* result in an object with mass attaining light speed. Through relativistic effects, the mass of the object will experience a gamma correction leading to ever decreasing accelerations. In fact the speed attainable is asymptotic to the speed of light.

Comment: So the space isnt empty and it consists of gas, photons and subatomic particles?

Comment: Note that the ever decreasing accelerations are decreasing from the perspective of an inertial observer. From the perspective of the accelerating mass, the acceleration is constant. Also, @SS4, you are correct. Space isn't quite empty.